# Intel Fortran Compiler License

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I remember once upon a time I paid for Intel compilers and tools and it was pretty worth it for the application at hand.  Now, I am building an object oriented database engine and am considering using a Fortran back end to compile a simple scripting language on the fly.  This seems pretty straightfoward, but what's the licensing like these days?  Is this open source?

Comment: It's not open source, but is freely downloadable as part of the Intel OpenApi HPC toolkit - https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/fortran-compiler.html#gs.e0i9ub I suggest you check the licencing yourself to see if it fits your needs

Comment: I think it can actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Intel oneAPI Toolkits are open source, you can download them for free. Please find the below links for downloading the latest Intel Base and HPC Toolkits.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/base-toolkit-download.html
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/hpc-toolkit-download.html

To access older releases you need a version that includes Intel Priority Support, the free versions do not include this.  Here is a link to the online store to get a commercially supported version. Please find the below link:
https://softwarestore.intel.com/

Thanks,
Varsha